# How to match value of one row with its immediate another row in different column in R

Tags: r

So I have this data of customers buying airline tickets online. I want to see how many of them have booked return tickets. So basically I want to match the origin city to the destination city of the immediate row and vice versa for the same PERSON and Account that will give me a data with their two way travel and then I want to calculate the days of their journey. I am trying to do this in R but I am unable to match origin with destination of the immediate row and vice versa.

I have sorted the account numbers of customers to manually see if there are any return journeys and there are quite a lot.

The data is like this:

```
Account number          origin city Destination city    Date
1                     London    chicago              7/22/2018
2                      Milan    London               7/23/2018
2                      London    Milan               7/28/2018
1                     chicago    london              8/22/2018
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to join to itself, with the fields reversed.

**Edit:** Added "trip_num" to deal better with repeated trips by the same person.

```
library(dplyr)
# First, convert date field to Date type
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>%
  # update with M-M's suggestion in comments
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(origin_city, Destination_city), .funs = toupper) %>%
  # EDIT: adding trip_num to protect against extraneous joins for repeat trips
  group_by(Account_number, origin_city, Destination_city) %>%
  mutate(trip_num = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("Account_number", "trip_num",
                       "origin_city" = "Destination_city",
                       "Destination_city" = "origin_city")) %>%
  mutate(days = (Date.x - Date.y)/lubridate::ddays(1))


> df2
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Account_number origin_city Destination_city Date.x     trip_num Date.y      days
           <int> <chr>       <chr>            <date>        <int> <date>     <dbl>
1              1 LONDON      CHICAGO          2018-07-22        1 2018-08-22   -31
2              2 MILAN       LONDON           2018-07-23        1 2018-07-28    -5
3              2 LONDON      MILAN            2018-07-28        1 2018-07-23     5
4              1 CHICAGO     LONDON           2018-08-22        1 2018-07-22    31
5              2 MILAN       LONDON           2018-08-23        2 2018-08-28    -5
6              2 LONDON      MILAN            2018-08-28        2 2018-08-23     5
```

---

Data:   (added repeat trip by Account_number 2)

```
df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "Account_number          origin_city Destination_city    Date
1                     London    chicago              7/22/2018
2                      Milan    London               7/23/2018
2                      London    Milan               7/28/2018
1                     chicago    london              8/22/2018
2                      Milan    London               8/23/2018
2                      London    Milan               8/28/2018")
```

Comment: why does it have NA in case of account 1? that is also a return journey.

Comment: needs `group_by` and `toupper`!

Comment: `df <- df %>% mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(origin_city, Destination_city), .funs = toupper)` You should do this before creating `df2` using Jon's code.

Comment: I just checked in detail and found out that its not working properly. The dates are getting duplicated in some cases and now the database has added more 30000 rows with the duplicated dates. I dont understand why some of the dates are getting duplicated and adding more rows on its own. Is there a way out?

Comment: There will be duplicates if the same Account number makes a round trip more than once; every "out" leg will be matched with every matching "return." One way to deal with this would be to number each cycle. I've edited to fix this.